# Recebimento de findAll() no nodejs

Tags: node.js

estou com uma duvida imensa aqui.

```
router.post('/login', (req,res)=>{
  Usuario.findAll({where: {email: req.body.email}}).then((x)=>{
   console.log(x.email)
  })
})
```

Resultado de 'console.log(x.email)' é undefined.
se eu fizer o console.log(x) o resultado é como na foto abaixo.
Eu preciso ter o conteudo do x.email pra realizar uma comparação.

Muito obrigado desde já.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `x` é um array, não um objeto. Você deve iterar sobre os elementos do array para acessá-los como objetos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o atributo `x` não é um objeto mas sim um array. Para obter o valor da propriedade `email` você precisará acessar o primeiro índice do array que guardará um objeto.

Depois disso, basta acessar a propriedade `dataValues` e assim obter o `email`, dessa forma:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    Usuario.findAll({where: {email: req.body.email}}).then((x) => {
       console.log(x[0].dataValues.email);
    });
});
```

Comment: realmente. não sei onde estava com a cabeça. obrigado! =) funcionou.